# How can I fetch the verification status of a Truecaller user profile?

Tags: java, android, sdk, lib

I'm using **Truecaller sdk** in my **Android app**, along with User details (name & company name) I want to know the verification status of a user.

For fetching user details, I'm using `TrueProfile` object received in `onSuccessProfileShared` callback of `ITrueCallback`

```
@Override
    public void onSuccessProfileShared(@NonNull TrueProfile trueProfile) {
         Log.d("Truecaller","getters \nfname : "+trueProfile.firstName+
               "\n lname : "+trueProfile.lastName+
              "\n company name : "+trueProfile.companyName);

}
```

However I have gone through the [official doc of truecaller](https://docs.truecaller.com/truecaller-sdk/mobile-websites/integrating-with-your-mobile-website/fetch-user-profile) and found a `JSON` response in which they have shown "verified" under badges key but I'm unable to fetch the same using `TrueProfile` object.

[image]

How can I fetch the verification status of a Truecaller user profile?

Answer (score 0):

the screenshot you have pasted here is the response for Truecaller's SDK for mobile websites, where in the JSON response is shared. For the android SDK which you are integrating, you need to look for the **isTrueName** parameter in the trueProfile object. isTrueName would be a boolean true/false value, indicating whether the user is a verified user or not.

**P.S** this verified status tells you whether the user has a verified badge on their Truecaller profile or not, although all the users who sign up via the Truecaller SDK on your app, would still anyways have their mobile number and name verified ( which you receive as part of the trueProfile ).